# how to put multiple markers on MapBox in android via geoJson?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I am trying to put about 40 markers on the map scattered across the large area. I found the code to do so but it clusters the nearby markers, but I want it to show all the markers as they are regardless of zoom levels.

These are the codes I tried.

1. [Mapbox github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/ImageClusteringActivity.java) :- It works fine but it makes clusters of nearby markers.
2. This code doesn't work for me as android can't resolve methods `featureCollection.getFeatures()`,`f.getGeometry()`,`mapView.addMarker`,`coordinates.getLatitude()` and `coordinates.getLongitude()`

   ```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

     private MapView mapView;


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);

         mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         mapView.getMapAsync(this);

     }

     @Override
     public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
         this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

         try{
             Uri uriMap = Uri.parse("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/9jln7v48lp3lb7e/data.geojson?dl=0");
             String geoJsonString = getStringFromFile(uriMap,MainActivity.this);

             GeoJsonSource source = new GeoJsonSource("geojson", geoJsonString);
             mapboxMap.addSource(source);
             mapboxMap.addLayer(new LineLayer("geojson", "geojson"));

             FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromJson(geoJsonString);

             List<Feature> features = featureCollection.getFeatures();

             for (Feature f : features) {
                 if (f.getGeometry() instanceof Point) {
                     Position coordinates = (Position)
                             f.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                     mapView.addMarker(
                             new MarkerViewOptions().position(new
                                     LatLng(coordinates.getLatitude(),
                                     coordinates.getLongitude()))
                     );
                 }
             }

         }catch(Exception e){
             Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

     }

     private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line).append("\n");
         }
         reader.close();
         return sb.toString();
     }

     public static String getStringFromFile(Uri fileUri, Context context) throws Exception {
         InputStream fin = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);

         String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);

         fin.close();
         return ret;
     }
   }
   ```

P.S it would be great if I can do it without any libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the linelayer that you create, it renders geojson directly when you call `source.setGeoJson(featureCollection)`.

To draw markers directly onto the map you need to call the addmarker method on the map instance, not the map view instance. In your case `mapboxMap.addMarker`

As for unresolved methods, you are likely not importing the correct packages:
`import com.mapbox.geojson.Feature;
import com.mapbox.geojson.FeatureCollection;`